# If $x^TAx$ = $x^TBx$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Then what can I say about the matrices? Are they congruent to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

If $x^TAx$ = $x^TBx$   for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Then what can I say about the matrices? Are they congruent to each other?

My attempt:
$x^TAx$ = $x^TBx$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Then I can say $A - B$  is skew-symmetric. I cannot see more than this.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I would say they are congruent, for example because each matrix can be written in Jordan normal form. The condition then implies that each generalized eigenvalue (which is the diagonal element of the Jordan block matrix) is the same. Hence we can write $A = PJP^{-1}$ and $B=QJQ^{-1}$. The assertion follows.

Comment: If $A-B$ is symmetric, then $A=B$.

Comment: @ThomasBakx Just because two Jordan matrices have the same diagonal elements does not mean they have the same block structure.

Comment: @cmi,  if you know how to prove that necessarily $A-B$ is skew symmetric, then you solved your problem. what do you need more?

Comment: I got stuck with this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734315/what-are-the-rank-and-signature-of-the-matrices-whose-quadraic-forms-are-xyz2..Can you please check this out?@angryavian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some terminology: for a matrix $A$, we say that a function $Q(x)=x^TAx$ is a *quadratic form generated by $A$*. As you can see, quadratic form depends only on the symmetric part of the matrix.

The statement

> $A$ and $B$ generate the same quadratic form, that is $x^TAx=x^TBx$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

is equivalent to

> $A-B$ is skew-symmetric.

In particular, they do not need to be congruent - for example the following matrices generate the same quadratic form ($Q(x)=0$):
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$
but surely they are not congruent as their determinants differ.

Comment: I took the liberty to change a bit the formatting of your post. Feel free to roll it back if you're not happy with the changes (by clicking on the "edited..." at the bottom center of your post) .

Comment: @Surb Thank you very much, it looks much better now!

Answer (score 0):

With $A=0$ and $B$ skew-symmetric you have $\forall x$:
$$x^t Ax=0=x^t Bx$$
but $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily congruent.