# On problem regarding the quadratic form $yx+z^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms

If $A$ be a Matrix of rank $4$ and signature $3$, then there can not be an invertible Matrix $P$ such that $v^t(P^tAP)v$ is $xy+z^2$. Here $v \in R^4$.

Comment: Are we considering $v^t(P^tAP)v$ or $v^t(P^{-1}AP)v$?

Comment: first one@gimusi please read my question rigorously and answer. I am getting confused.

Comment: What does signature mean for you?  It does not seem possible to have a 4x4 matrix of rank 4 and signature 3, because p-n=3 and p+n=4 has no solution.

Comment: number of positive $1$. Are you the same @Vadim who has solved Mukresh?

Comment: Sorry, no idea who Mukresh is.

Comment: But ur solution helped me a lot. BTW did u understand where is my problem @vadim123

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks Vadim but don't undelete please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix B associated to $xy+z^2$ is

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac12&0&0\\\frac12&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

with signature

$$n_+=2,n_-=1,n_0=1$$

and this is a contradiction since A and B should be [congruent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues).

Comment: Can you please read my question once again? @gimusi

Comment: @cmi I think it suffices note that rank(B)=3.

Comment: Why you have to invoke the associated Matrix with that quadratic form? Is there any relation between the Matrices which have that quadratic form and the associated Matrix of the same?

Comment: @cmi to deduce the signature of $xy+z^2$, as Vladim noted it suffices to observe that $B$ has a eigenvalue $= 0$ (since $\det(B)=0$) and that suffices to exclude that $A$ and $B$ are congruent that is that P exists such that $B=P^TAP$.

Comment: I am claiming that there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that $v^tP^tAPv$  is $xy +z^2$. now you are claiming it can not happen because the Matrix which has this quadratic form has rank $3$ and the rank of $A$ is $4$. How would you know that? Is there any relationship between the matrix whose quadratic form is that and the matrix which associated with the same. It is my question.@gimusi

Comment: you are not getting my point@gimusi

Comment: @cmi Ah ok you can't see why B is associated to $xy+z^2$?

Comment: @cmi Once you see that $x^TBx=xy+z^2$ you only need to refer to "Sylvester's law of inertia" whic states that "two symmetric square matrices of the same size have the same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues if and only if they are congruent, that is $B=P^TAP$". But $A$ has $4$ eigenvalues $\neq 0$ (signature 3 and rank 4) and $B$ has an eigenvalue$=0$. That is a contradiction.

Comment: $x^tBx$ = $xy +z^2$ = $x^tP^tAPX$ so you are claiming $B$ and $P^tAP$ are congruent. Am I correct?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi Yes of course! refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues

Comment: so you are basically claiming if $x^tAx$ = $x^tBx$ for all $x $, then $A$ and $B$ are congruent. Am I correct?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi No it is not correct! We are making a lot of confusion here. Let start again. The OP is claiming that "If $A$ be a matrix of rank $4$ and signature $3$, then there can not be an invertible matrix $P$ such that $v^t(P^tAP)v$ is $xy+z^2$" and this claim is true since $B=P^tAP$ should be congruent with $A$, that is should have the same signature but the signature for $B$ is different.

Comment: I became more confused now.@gimusi  I am claiming that there exists a non singular matrix such that $P$ such that $v^tP^tAPv$ is $xy + z^2$. Now you are saying it can not happen because the Matrix associated with the quadratic form $xy + z^2$ is of rank $3$.Why the Matrix associated with the quadratic form $xy + z^2$ has to be invoked?

Comment: @cmi What is the point that is not clear to you?

Comment: I am claiming that there exists a non singular matrix such that $P$ such that $v^tP^tAPv$ is $xy + z^2$. Now you are saying it can not happen because the Matrix associated with the quadratic form $xy + z^2$ is of rank $3$.Why the Matrix associated with the quadratic form $xy + z^2$ has to be invoked?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi Exactly it cannot happen since A has signature 3 and rank 4 that is has 3 positive eigenvalues and 1 negative eigenvalue but the matrix associated to $xy + z^2$ has a different signature and in particular has rank 3 and thus an eigenvalue$=0$. Therefore, by Sylvester's Law, P not singular doesn't esists such that $x^TP^TAPx=x^TBx=xy+z^2$ since in this case A nd be should be congruent that is A and B should have the same signature.

Comment: YOU are saying the same thing. Everything is okay but why you are relating $A$ and $B$.Where the hell $B$ come form?  @gimusi

Comment: @cmi Can you see the relation between B and $xy+z^2$?

Comment: YES. But why B will be invoked?

Comment: You did not read my questions or comments anything. You only have been trying to stick to your opinion.@gimusi

Comment: okk ...leave it..I do not think. I will get my doubt cleared here.@gimusi

Comment: @cmi Because we are claiming that $x^TP^TAPx=xy+z^2$ then we are interested to determine the signature of $P^TAP=B$. I'm sorry I can't explain it better. What about vadim123 explanation?

Comment: @cmi Note that the title of your OP is "What are the Rank and Signature of the matrices whose quadratic forms are $xy+z^2$?" and the aswer to that is: rank=3 and signature (2,1,0). From here you can deduce all what you need. I really can't help you more than that. I'm sorry that you get angry for that but please keep calm, collaborative and polite. I'm honestly made my effort to can help you. Forgive me if I can't.

Comment: @amd Could you please try to give an answer about this OP? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help me@gimusi

Comment: I want to upvote this answer. But I can not. Can you please edit something so that I can upvote?@gimusi

Answer (score 0):

Okay, by hypotheses, $A$ is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $diag(1,1,1-1)$.  [It has three positive eigenvalues, and no zero eigenvalues.]

By Sylvester's law of inertia, if $A$ were congruent to $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1/2&0&0\\1/2&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
then $B$ would have three positive eigenvalues and one negative one (and no zero eigenvalues).  However, instead $B$ has two positive, one negative, and one zero eigenvalue.  Hence $A$ and $B$ cannot be congruent.

Comment: why $A$ has to be congruent to $B$? That is where I am having problem.  @vadim123

Comment: I am finding an invertible Matrix $P$ such that $v^tP^t A Pv$ is $xy +z^2$.

Comment: $B$ is the (symmetric) matrix representing the quadratic form $xy+z^2+0w^2$, for $v=(x,y,z,w)$.

Comment: Is there only one matrix whose quadratic form is that? Can there be not any $P^t A P$ whose quadratic form is that?

Comment: Why you have to invoke the associated Matrix with that quadratic form? Is there any relation between the Matrices which have that quadratic form and the associated Matrix of the same?

Comment: I am claiming that there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that $v^tP^tAPv$  is $xy +z^2$. now you are claiming it can not happen because the Matrix which has this quadratic form has rank $3$. How would you know that? It is my question.@vadim123

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms

Comment: hiii@vadim123 Can you understand where I am having problem? If you understand please don't ignore me. I want an answer otherwise I can not sleep. It's 12.55 a.m in India.

Comment: I have read that. But is that my doubt's answer?@vadim123

Comment: Dear cmi,  neither I nor gimusi can figure out where your confusion is.  We have both given correct and complete answers to the problem.

Comment: Dear @vadim123 I am extremely sorry to let you know that answers given by you and  gimiusi were not my question's answer.

Comment: THIS IS NOT MY ANSWER. NOT ACCEPTED AT ALL...